# Changing Icon and HTML Title in DASH

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Is it possible to change the icon and title of an HTML page generated from a Dash Python application?

I used the following code, but it didn't work

```
import dash
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Meta([
    html.Link(
        rel='icon',
        href='assets/icon.ico',
        type='imagex/ico'
    ),
    html.Title(
        title='My App'
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: You can set the title via the Dash constructor, ie `Dash(title='...')`. You can set the favicon _and_ title (and other things) via the [`app.interpolate_index`](https://dash.plotly.com/reference#app.interpolate_index) method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this

```py
app = Dash(__name__)
app.title = "My title"
app._favicon = ("my_icon.png")
```

The icon image file has to be in the *assets* folder